# Swift: Using argument as default value for a different argument in the same function

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to define a function to present a mail composer. It takes the delegate and the presenter `UIViewController` as argument (not always is the same) but I wan't to provide a default value for cases where the presenter and the delegate are the same `UIViewController`. Is that possible?

```
internal func showMailComposer(presenterController: UIViewController, delegate: UIViewController = presenterController, recipient: String = "", subject: String = "", body: BodyMessage = BodyMessage(string: "", isHTML: false)) {

    guard let delegate = delegate as? MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate else { return }

    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make `delegate` an *Optional* with default `nil` and then use `??` to unwrap it or replace it with `presenterController` if none is provided:

```
internal func showMailComposer(presenterController: UIViewController, delegate: UIViewController? = nil, recipient: String = "", subject: String = "", body: BodyMessage = BodyMessage(string: "", isHTML: false)) {

    guard let delegate = (delegate ?? presenterController) as? MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate else { return }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Nice approach. Thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 1):

Like 0xa6a said, I don't think that this is possible as the default values should be available at compile time. Another option to achieve similar behaviour is to convert the parameter to objects and implement the logic there. It is just a matter of personal preference and style. Here is a suggestion:

```
struct Mail{
   let recipient: String = ""
   let subject: String = ""
   let body: BodyMessage = BodyMessage(string: "", isHTML: false)
}

struct MailPresenter{

   weak var presenter : UIViewController?
   weak var delegate : MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate?

   init(using presenter: UIViewController?, mailDelegate: MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate? = nil){

      self.presenter = presenter

      if let mailDelegate = mailDelegate{
        self.delegate = mailDelegate
      }else{
        self.delegate = presenter as? MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate
      }
    }
 }
internal func showMailComposer(from presenter: MailPresenter , for mail: Mail = Mail() ) {

}
```

And you can use it, like this:

```
showMailComposer(from: MailPresenter(using: yourViewController))
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do that in Swift. And that looks weird even if it's possible.

## ps:

Why don't define the argument `presenterController` as `MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate`. It'll be more explicit, like this:

```
internal func showMailComposer(presenterController: UIViewController, delegate: MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate, recipient: String = "", subject: String = "", body: BodyMessage = BodyMessage(string: "", isHTML: false)) {

    // ...
}
```